# Какие недостатки имеет тип ntext по сравнению с nvarchar ?

Tags: sql-server

Необходимо хранить и обрабатывать длинные тексты на русском. Не получается определиться с выбором типа исходя из msdn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ntext - устаревший тип, только nvarchar надо использовать.

Comment: А есть ему новая замена без ограничения на 8000 символов ?

Comment: nvarchar(max) притом.

Comment: nvarchar(max) имеет ограничение в 2Гб, а никак не 8000 символов.